# How do I paste the contents of a folder into the www root folder?

Tags: command-line, files

I want to take the contents of `home/magpie/xoops-2.5.5/htdocs/` and put it into `var/www` using the terminal. I don't want to go downloading anything I don't need.

Comment: Please clarify a bit (the situation).What version are you using. Your question not answerable in current form.

Comment: I want to take the contents of home/magpie/xoops-2.5.5/htdocs/ and put it into var/www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to take the contents of home/magpie/xoops-2.5.5/htdocs/ and put it into var/www*

To do what you want, open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T` and type:

```
cp -vR /home/magpie/xoops-2.5.5/htdocs/* /var/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy everything (including subdirectories) into the root (/) folder you would

1. Change to that directory

   ```
   cd DIR
   ```
2. Then copy everything to the root folder

   ```
   cp -R * /
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I want everything in there but that is useful to know anyway! I only want the contents of a particular folder at the moment